# Batch: Created variable in loop cannot be used outside

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to analyze a file using a batch. The file has a folder on the top level. This folder is named different for each file, however the is every time just one folder (besides some other files on the top level).

To get the path for the folder my approach was to loop through all existing folders on top level in a FOR and in each iteration creating the path name. As there is just one folder every time I have only 1 iteration like so:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b %temp_dir%') do (
    set "folderPath=%%~D"
    set "FullFolderPath=%temp_dir%\!folderPath!"
    echo !FullFolderPath!
)
echo %FullFolderPath%
```

The problem: The first echo inside the loop output the correct path to the folder but the second echo just stated `<ECHO OFF>`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] of your code.  As it stands it is not complete or reproduceable.

Comment: @Zilog80: I think you confused something. What you describe is true for the `in` clause, but not for the `do` clause (which you successfully proved in your linked answer). @SRel: your code seems to work as expected for me (last line echoing the last found folder name or `ECHO is OFF` when there were no matching folders (and so the `do` clause isn't executed at all).

Comment: @Stephan You're right, i've confused, It is for the IN clause not the DO clause. I'm old...

Comment: `I'm old...` - I guessed so from your username `:D` (being able to do so proves I'm probably in the same range...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (I'm about 90% certain), that the second echo is still in a parenthesis block.

If it's in *any* parenthesis block, the value of the variable queried with the % signs will expand to the last set value that was set outside the parenthesis.

---

You might accidentally left an ubalanced parenthesis in your code,that didnt crash it, but still caused this problem.
You can troubleshoot it by setting the variable before each parenthesis block.